# How to get a Standard Deviation weighted average in image?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, algorithms, gaussian

Now I'm trying to implement a SDLWGW algorithm by the MATLAB.
currently I'm referencing from [Automatic White Balancing Using Luminance Component and Standard Deviation of RGB Components](https://winnie.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/local/CDROM/icassp04/pdfs/0300493.pdf)

The problem is I can't understand  how to get a $SDLWA_{R}$ and $\overline{L_{red}(k)}$?
Also what if the $L_{weight}(i,j)$ is $0.9$ then how to calculate the bar of $L_{red}(k)$?

I can't understand it.

I want to know that what is the different between $SD_{red}(k)$ and $SD_{red}(l)$?

$$SDLWA_{R}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{SD_{red}(k)}{\sum_{l=1}^{n}SD_{red}(l)}\times red_{i,j}(k) $$

What is the $SD_{red}(l)$? Especially, what is the $l$?

$$ \sum_{l=1}^{n}SD_{red}(l) $$

## Update 1

I have got a question one more,

The paper was written like this
`L_weight(i,j)` is a positive single-peak function (e.g Triangular function or Gaussian function) value for the luminance value at `i-th` row, `j-th` column of the `k-th` block. But I can't understand what is the mean? How can I make `L_weight(i,j)`?
Would you please give me any hint please ?

## Update 2

I'm trying to understand a below answer.

Q1. What if I've got a this block then I think that the $k$ is to
be $12$ and $p$ is $5$, and $q$ is $5$. am I correct?

Q2. How to get a $\overline{L\_red(k)}$ value as below the case?

Q2-1. Especially, I want to know that what does exactly indicate the $L\_weight(1,1)red_{1,1}(k)$ and $L\_weight(1,1)$, as below the case?
I think we know the value of the $red_{1,1}(k)$ But I'm confused that how to know the value of $L\_weight(1,1)$ ?

[image]

## Update 3

Does anyone know the relationship between Gaussian weight and one Block?

Comment: The bar denotes the average over a set of pixels. Please try to rewrite it, and propose a beginning of a Matlab code, so that we can help you where you stop understanding

Comment: @LaurentDuval would you give some hint about what is the different between x,y and i,j in Figure3? I don't have a quite bit understand. I can  to assume that that i,j are involved in K then what is the x,y?

Comment: This person has created new accounts to spam questions on this particular topic. It seems like he/she is trying to accomplish a very specific task of image processing, but without the required background and knowledge. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808504/how-to-get-a-standard-deviation-weighted-average-in-image

Comment: @jojek  Thanks, I have no idea, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k$ and $l$ indices are to be understood with indexes under the $\sum$ sign. They can be called "free variables". Suppose that the block $k$ has only two pixels, then $p=1$ and $q=2$. So $\overline{L\_red(k)} $ is just a weighted average (a kind of center of mass) of the $2$ red components from the two pixels  of the block:
$$ \frac{L\_weight(1,1)red_{1,1}(k)+L\_weight(1,2)red_{1,2}(k)}{L\_weight(1,1)+L\_weight(1,2)} $$
which gives you a single value for each block.
Formula (5) has the same interpretation,  you perform the weighted average of those averaged values over blocks, with weights $SD\_red(k)$.

it is quite easy to use [Matlab's block processing tools](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/blockaverage).

Comment: I have updated with some confused things.

Comment: $L\_weight(i,j)$ is a discrete function with the same size of each block, so you multiply coordinate-wise each pixel of the block by the corresponding pixel in $L\_weight(i,j)$ (Q2-1), sum all $p\times q$ products, and divide by the sum of pixles in  $L\_weight(i,j)$ (Q2).  On the bottom of page 495, the authors seem to take a constant value. Q1: $p=q=5$, but the block is the first one, $k=1$.

Comment: at the Q2, I think the authors said that "L_weight(i,j) is a positive single-peak function (e.g triangular function or Gaussian function) value for the
luminance value at i-th row, j-th column of the k-th block." the L_weight doesn't seem to be one constant value. But I'm not sure.

Comment: You are correct, I talked about the last paragraph. You can use that code to generate 2D windows http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43827-two-dimensional-window-generator--2d-window-

Comment: But I'm not still understand how to use the Gaussian function to L_weight(i,j).

Comment: From the link above, compute a Gaussian window with w=window2(p,q,@gausswin ). Then you have your $L$ with the size of the block.

Comment: Apparently you have difficulties with the most basic image processing concepts. Why are you interested in this paper?

Comment: Can you tell me why does the Gaussian window affect to each blocks? I mean that what if I use that kind of method, then the major peak point always has to be center pixel of the block. isn't it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with paper equations so I am asking to expert. and I heard that this paper result are good.

Comment: Suppose you have a block $R$ of size $p\times q$, and a window $L$ with the same size. In Matlab, do $L.*R$

Comment: I believe I have provided you with a lot of details, and answered your questions. Would you be so kind as to accept my answer?

Comment: I got it Sir that "Suppose you have a block RR of size p×qp×q, and a window LL with the same size. In Matlab, do L.∗R" But my question is that Why do we use like that Gaussian method in the a block? I think there is no reason like to do that (using the Gaussian in a Block).

Comment: Thank you. I am not really sure, as I have not tried it myself. I suppose it gives more importance to the center of each block. The real answer is unknown to me

Comment: Welcome, / BTW. I don't think so because that the all of k is separated from one picture.  so I can't find any relationship between Gaussian weight and block R.